# Can not recognise this piece of equipment. It is attached to the mains

Tags: mains, electrical

[image: Unrecognised equipment]
It is normally quite noisy, but has gone silent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The black box with white text in a circle is a **week timer**.

Not how there are Roman numerals: I - II - III - IV - V - VI - VII

which is 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 for the days of the week.

There are "6", "18" and "24" to indicate the hours of a day.

The green jumpers are the "ON" jumpers.

The red jumpers are the "OFF" jumpers.

These clocks are powered by a [synchronous motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_motor) which rotates very accurately because it uses the mains frequency (50 Hz or 60 Hz) to rotate at the correct speed.

These motors have quite thin wires inside and sometimes these just break.

As this is all **mains powered** you should call an electrician to replace the clock.

Comment: @nuruvimama If I am reading the timer correctly, it looks like something is turned on at 06:00 and turns off at 00:00 every day.  With the clock stopped in that position, it will now be permanently on.  Do you know what it was controlling?

Comment: @naruvimama the person above misspelled your name in the notification so I'm giving you a proper notification.

Comment: @HandyHowie Sorry, I did not notice your comment earlier. I think it is the electrical radiators. That seems to make sense, if the pervious owner wants to turn off the radiators while she is sleeping? Now that I have a heat pump I do not really use any of the radiators.